Is The Orville dead?
When I stopped paying attention to the issue a year(?) or so ago, everyone was hoping it  would come back. They saved the sets, for instance.
Whatever happened to that? Is the show dead now permanently?

The show will be returning for at least one more season. Production starts in January 2025.

Alright, faithful, get your asses in here! This is something we’ve known for quite a while but haven’t been able to tell anyone until now since Scott broke the seal at STLV last night. S4 production is slated to kick off in January 2025.
Edited for additional clarity: We just want you all to understand that it will still be some time to ramp up before anyone is filming. Ted S2 is shooting first and then sets will need to be rebuilt, etc etc. Didn’t want to give anyone the false sense of actual filming beginning in January.
The Orville Season 4 Production Start January 2025: Official Podcast

Based on the average lag between filming and airing (on previous seasons of The Orville), this would suggest that the next season of the show will air sometimes around March 2026.
